# Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 display resolution too high installing on Hyper-V

Tags: server, display-resolution, hyper-v

Ubuntu Server install resolution on 20.04.1 versus 22.04.1:

[image: Ubuntu Server install resolution on 20.4.1 versus 22.4.1]

I've been using Ubuntu Server as a guest VM on a Windows Server 2012R2 host for some time. Currently it's still running 16.04.7 and I want to upgrade or replace with a new system running 22.4.1, but when I created a new VM using the 22.4.1 ISO, I noticed the console window from Hyper-V was larger than my display.  It seems to be defaulting to 1600x1200 while I'm running through an RDP to the Windows host using a resolution of 1680x1050. There's more vertical height in the terminal than available on the host system especially considering the Hyper-V console has its own window and toolbar. I thought maybe it was just a setting that would be better once everything was installed, but it hasn't. I did a lot of searching on changing the terminal resolution and they all seem to be about editing the grub settings such as GRUB_GFXMODE and others but none of them have changed anything. As a test, I created another new VM with everything the same but using the Ubuntu Server 20.4.1 and it worked just fine.  This seemed to use a 1152x864 resolution which fits just fine. My attached screenshot shows the two windows overlapped with the scrollbars on the larger meaning that I can't see both the install options at the top and the buttons for OK/Back at the bottom.

Again I'd be fine if this was just some default on the setup if any of the options for setting the terminal resolution after installation worked. I'll be using SSH and Webmin once it's running to manage it, but if I need to get on the console to address some issue, I don't want to have to deal with this issue.  Also note that I installed 20.04.1 and then upgraded to 22.04.1 and that also caused the working lower resolution to increase to the same 1600x1200 that doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestion what changed between 20.04 and 22.04 that changed the default for this?  Do you have any recommendations for how this can be changed?